# Can I return `Task.WhenAll()` instead of awaiting it?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I saw that everyone uses `Task.WhenAll` like in case 1. Can I just return `Task` which `Task.WhenAll` returns inside case 2?

Additional questions:

1. Is case 2 will be executed sync or not?
2. If i'll call `MethodAsync()` inside async method and await it, will I have 3 opened threads (main thread, `MethodAsync` thread, `Task.WhenAll()` thread). Will one thread wait next thread for completition?
3. Which one case is better to use according to performance?

```cs
// case 1
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(...);
}

// case 2
public Task MethodAsync()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(...);
}
```

Comment: Also see [Difference between returning and awaiting a Task in an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110213/difference-between-returning-and-awaiting-a-task-in-an-async-method) (and its duplicates)

Comment: [eliding async await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: `will I have 3 opened threads` - No; tasks aren't threads.