# Why can an async method with return type ValueTask await a regular Task without generating a compiler error?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, valuetask

The following code does not compile

```
public ValueTask Foo()
{
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

but yields an `Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask` as expected.

However, this

```
public async ValueTask Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

does compile fine.

I was just wondering how this works. Is this all down to compiler magic and its async-await syntactic sugar or is there something else going on?

For context: I came across this when implementing `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()`.

Comment: "Is this all down to compiler magic and its async-await syntactic sugar" In short, yes :)

Comment: _Basically_, an `async Task` is a `void` with some funkiness going on as to when it starts, pauses and completes and what happens when it does so, while a `Task` is merely a synchronous method returning a `Task`. The former can't return anything. So yes, but also no.

Comment: In the second example,  there are two completely separate tasks - once which the compiler is generating representing the completion of your method and the second one which you got from `Task.Delay` that is largely irrelevant to the task state machine for the method.

Comment: Take a look at the [decompiled code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBUAWATgKYCGwAlgHYDmA3MmpnAKwMoDMmM6AwugG9k6EZi5QAHJgBs6AEKlCACgCUyIUlGYAnDOwARYgBtSATyVxUVlewC+yW0A==). You can see that there's quite a lot going on in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this all down to compiler magic and its async-await syntactic sugar?

In short, yes. Whenever you `await`, the compiler needs to generate a state machine for that method. The task returned from the method then, is one that "represents" the state machine, rather than the single task that you are awaiting.

As a result, it doesn't matter *what* tasks you are awaiting anymore. The compiler just has to build the state machine according to where your `await`s are in your method, and then build a new task.

Compare the code generated from the following snippets on SharpLab:

[1](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMCsDcBYAUCAHFAbBAQgQwCcAKAShQG8UJqoBOLAOgBEBTAGzwE8jow+SkyAL5A=):

```
async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

[2](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMCsDcBYAUCAHBAagQwDYFcBTEANggCFsAnACgEoUBvFCVqATihIDoARQ3NgCeNaGHF0kyAL5A==):

```
async ValueTask Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

The only substantial difference is that one uses [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder?view=net-7.0) to build the task being returned, and the other using [`AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncvaluetaskmethodbuilder?view=net-7.0).

For more details about the difference of awaiting a task vs directly returning the task, see [this chain of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110213/5133585).

Answer (score 2):

Title doesn't match what's being asked. In fact, the question proves it's possible.

If you want to return `ValueTask` that represents a `Task` whithout having a method turned into a state machine, you can:

```cs
public ValueTask Foo()
{
    return new ValueTask(Task.Delay(1000));
}
```

Comment: I changed `How` into `Why` in the title. Hope that's better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Inside async method, you must return inner type of task, but you cannot return a task itself:

```cs
public async Task<int> Foo()
{
    return 42; // that works
}

public async Task<int> Foo()
{
    return Task.FromResult(42); // error
}
```

Look at the first example again: you don't need any task at all to return something from async method. `async` keyword acts as some sort of wrap operator, that transforms any `T` type to `Task<T>`. And it can work with any task-like type.

On the other hand, `await` operator acts like unwrap operator that transforms any `Task<T>` type into inner type `T`:

```cs
public async void Foo()
{
    int x = await Task.FromResult(42); // that works
}

public async void Foo()
{
    int x = Task.FromResult(42); // error
}

public async void Foo()
{
    int x = await 42; // error too
}
```

And `await` operator can work with any awaitable type, such as [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-7.0), [ValueTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=net-7.0), [ConfiguredTaskAwaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable-1?view=net-7.0), even [YieldAwaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.yieldawaitable?view=net-7.0)

And this two operators can be combined in any way.

Let's look again in your code:

```cs
public async ValueTask Bar()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

First, `await` transforms `Task` into `void`. Next, `async` transforms implicit `void` into `ValueTask`. There are nothing to wonder here.